# How to disable array's item in loop?

Tags: c#, arrays, routes

I am trying to get route between points from my array.When it get route between two points, for example;

```
getRoute(array[0],array[1])
```

after that, I want to remove `array[0]` item and check route between `array[1]` and other array items. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Route is the custom class that your getRoute-method returns.
var routes = new List<Route>();  

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
{
    routes.Add(getRoute(array[i], array[i + 1]));
}
```

Ok, based on the comment below, perhaps this is what you want?

```
var sequence = new int[] { 0, 3, 1, 4, 8 };

// Route is the custom class that your getRoute-method returns.
var routes = new List<Route>();  

for (int i = 0; i < sequence.Length - 1; i++)
{
    routes.Add(getRoute(array[sequence[i]], array[sequence[i + 1]]));
}
```

Comment: it's not sequent ,  for example route can be ; 0-1-3-5-4